# Delay an init script until another process is finished?

Tags: init-script, init.d

I am running debian Jessie. During startup I want to read some user input. This is done by a custom script in /etc/init.d/ and symlinks in the runlevel dirs. Now I want  `kdm`, which is started by another init script, to be started only after my custom script is finished.

I cloud achieve this by adding something like

```
while test -e /tmp/kdm-boot-lock
do
    echo "waiting for lock-file to be deleted by custom-script"
    sleep 1
done
```

to /etc/init.d/kdm

but I would prefer a solution without changing foreign files (which might get changed by updates).

So the question is: How can I prevent that a distinct (unchanged) init script (`kdm`) is started before my custom script finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using initscripts, the right way to defer `kdm` until your custom script has finished is to declare a dependency from `kdm` on your custom script, in the LSB header:

```
# Required-Start: ... yourscript
```

in the `kdm` initscript, and

```
# Provides: yourscript
```

in your custom initscript.

To avoid the changes to the `kdm` initscript being lost on upgrades, you can copy its LSB header to an `insserv` override file in `/etc/insserv/overrides` (with the same name), and edit that instead.

Comment: Thanks,  but this does not solve the problem. It only achieves (due to symlink naming) that kdm is started after custom_script is _started_ but it does not achive that kdm is started after custom_script is _finished_.